# Regular expression to check if a given password contains at least one number and one letter in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Can anyone help me write a regular expression for checking if a password has at least one letter and one number in it?

I have a requirement that users passwords must be alphanumeric and I want to be able to check for that using a regular expression.

Comment: @Paco: I wasn't aware that Stack Overflow only allows difficult questions!

Comment: I agree with Luke. Stack Overflow doesn't have to be for the seasoned professional having a problem decompiling bytecode, or 'where is the WMI documentation'.

Comment: This problem is too practical to be homework.

Comment: What makes this a bad question (IMO) is that you can so easily find a solution by googling: http://www.google.com/#q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+regex+password  *Hundreds* of hits, and that's just here on SO!

Comment: @Luke: That is true, but when you look for regex questions in stack overflow, a very large part of them is about so simple and basic regexes, that it looks like that some people post a question on stack overflow for every regex they need to write. A lot of those are asked several times already like Alan M says.

Comment: http://www.rubular.com/r/wdmyC43XGq

Answer (score 21):

**Positive lookahead** is what you're looking for. The regex looks like this:

```
(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]+
```

Here, `(?=.*[A-Za-z])` is the positive lookahead which asserts that your string as **at least one character**, and `(?=.*[0-9])` asserts that it has **at least one digit**. It's important to note that the positive lookahead doesn't return a match, but rather asserts whether a match exists or not. So, you should read the previous regex as "assert that it has at least one character; assert it has at least one digit; now that we know the assertions have passed, just check for alphanumeric characters".

This is very interesting because it allows you to easily combine the validation requirements of your application, without making your regex very complex. For example, if you now require the string to have **exactly** 20 characters, you just need to add a new positive lookahead assertion, like so:

```
(?=[A-Za-z0-9]{20})(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]+
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: why not this? (?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]{20}

Comment: Why do you need `.*` in your positive lookahead? I'm not understanding how the result would be different if you omitted it.

Answer (score 7):

If you want it in one regex you can use `"[a-zA-Z].*\\d|\\d.*[a-zA-Z]"` though two seperate checks may be more readable.

Edit: An approach with two checks, which I find quite readable, might look like this:

```
Regex.IsMatch(password, "\\d") && Regex.IsMatch(password, "[a-zA-Z]")
```

Comment: And then you'd need an extra check to test if it has alphanumeric characters only.

Answer (score 2):

```
bool isValid = Regex.IsMatch(password, @"[a-zA-Z]") &&
               Regex.IsMatch(password, @"\d");
```