# Regular Expression for Password

Tags: c#, .net, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular expression to check if a given password contains at least one number and one letter in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316750/regular-expression-to-check-if-a-given-password-contains-at-least-one-number-and)

I need to create regular expression for password with following requirement:

Min 2 Small char
Min 2 Caps char
Min 1 Special char (!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,),~) 
Min 2 numeric
Min Length 8 chars

Can anyone give the regular expression for above specification?

Note: I have already implemented this without Regex using different logic. But, regular expressions are powerful than the manual processing.

Comment: Are you required to use a regular expression for this? It would be much easier (and far more readable) if you didn't use a regex.

Comment: At the very least, you'll need to define "special char".

Comment: Any particular programming language?

Comment: Did you even try researching this yourself?

Comment: `\*{8}\**`  :o)  (joke of course)

Comment: Really? People upvoted this, presumably to counteract my down-vote. Despite the fact that entering the question into Google returns a stack of helpful results. Reminder that questions are supposed to show some effort on the part of the question asker.

Comment: There are dozens of RegEx4Password questions on SO. Enough for you to make a start and ask a specific question if none of them can be adapted to your requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expressions aren't particularly well suited for this type of task.

You could probably solve it, possibly using zero-width assertions / look arounds. However, it seems to me like you're after validating some users choice of password.

Even if you *did* come up with a match / no match regular expression, how would you provide useful feed-back to the user if the password didn't match the expression? Would you say "*The password you entered does not conform to these five constraints.....*". Wouldn't it be much nicer if the user was told something like "*Your password must be at least 8 characters*".

If you are indeed validating some users input, it sounds to me like you would be better off checking each constraint one by one.

Comment: I ended up writing method to validate all 5 points separately. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the function that i use is this.

function check_pass_strength($pwd)
{

```
    if( strlen($pwd) > 20 ) {
    $error .= "Password too long! <br />";
}

if( strlen($pwd) < 8 ) {
    $error .= "Password too short , minimum 8 characters! <br />";
}

if( !preg_match("#[0-9]+#", $pwd) ) {
    $error .= "Password must include at least one number! <br />";
}


if( !preg_match("#[a-z]+#", $pwd) ) {
    $error .= "Password must include at least one letter! <br />";
}


if( !preg_match("#[A-Z]+#", $pwd) ) {
    $error .= "Password must include at least one CAPS! <br />";
}



if( !preg_match("#\W+#", $pwd) ) {
    $error .= "Password must include at least one symbol! <br />";
}


if($error){
    echo "Password validation failure(your choise is weak):<br /> $error";
    return 0;
} else {
    return 1;
}
```

} 
you can modify it for your needs and voila!!

Comment: that's php! The OP is about C#. Besides you are using 4 RegExs to decide whether the password matches all conditions, seems a bit of a costly procedure, imho.